# Can RSA key be used as key for symmetric encryption?

Tags: rsa

I know RSA is asymmetric (public / private) key.
But, is possible to generate only a
private key with rsa and using it as symmetric?
For example with openssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key used for symmetric encryption is usually random. An RSA key is not random and there are only comparable few RSA private keys for a given key length compared to all possible keys of this length. Thus while it in theory could be used as key for symmetric encryption it would be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, i want only know if was possible to use RSA for symmetric encryption, just for know it

Comment: @elbarna: See also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180187/why-cant-the-rsa-algorithm-be-used-for-symmetric-key-infrastructures